# changing the ionic2 side menu toggle effect

Tags: ionic2

currently ionic2 side menu toggle effect is from **left to right** or **right to left**. But according to my requirement, i need menu toggle effect from **top to bottom**. Is it possible to change the menu toggle effect?

Comment: `menuToggle top` i have not tried yet but if this does not works for you then place an issue to ionic team

Comment: Why not use a transparent modal ?..you will need a custom solution. Its not normal for a side menu to come from the top